# Create a Horizontal Scroll Tab for Ajax Tab Container

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, tabcontainer

I got many tabs inside ajax tab container that cannot be fit into one row. So I would like to create a horizontal scroll tab for ajax tab container to fit all tabs into a single row.

I have tried research online for quite awhile but still couldn't find a solution to it. My ajax tab container and tab panel would be created dynamically in c#.
This is the output that I would like to achieve:(See Below:)

[image]

This is my codes:

```
    //Aspx file
 <div>
             <asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:scriptmanager>
        </div>
        <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
            <contenttemplate>
        <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>

                <asp:Chart runat="server">

                </asp:Chart>

            </contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>

//Cs file
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
            container.ID = "TabContainer";
            container.EnableViewState = false;
            container.Tabs.Clear();
            container.Height = Unit.Pixel(2000);
            container.Width = Unit.Pixel(2000);
            container.Tabs.AddAt(0, GetManualTab());

  AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                    panel.HeaderText += item.Text;
                    container.Tabs.Add(panel);
```

Question: How to create a **horizontal scroll tab** for ajax tab container in order to fit many tabs into **one row**?

Appreciate if someone could provide me help on this. Thanks!

Regards,

Felicia

Comment: TabContainer has a ScrollBars property. i'm not sure where the scrollbar is placed though. `container.ScrollBars` i assume.

Comment: just looked more closely. i think i remember trying to get that to work a long time ago. i still can't. i don't think it can be done. anyone else?